# Default eclipse working directory

Tags: java, eclipse

Is it possible to set a default working directory in Eclipse 3.4.1? By Default that is:

${workspace_loc:(project name)}

But I want it to be something like

${custom_var}

Per class, I can change the Run configuration -> arguments -> Working directory to "Other", but it's better if the default can be changed. I have a lot of classes that needs to be run from that particular directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is set up one launch configuration and then right-click it and choose "duplicate". This will keep all the arguments.

Not perfect, but AFAIK there is no way to change the default working dir, though.

You can also set the dir you want as a string substitution (Window->Preferences->Run/Debug->String Substitution) and then use that variable in each run config - you'll still have to set it but instead of picking the dir each time you just choose the variable.

Comment: Indeed there seems no way to change the default working dir. But thx for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

Just created: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=301527

Comment: @rwst - not remarkable at all.  Only 3 people have bothered to vote for it so far.