# How to find my old Eclipse workspace?

Tags: eclipse

I had a bunch of things go wrong after I reinstalled Eclipse, and now it doesn't even start.

I saw on some forum that deleting old workspaces might help. How do I locate the old Eclipse workspace on my Windows 7 pc?

This is the error that I get in Eclipse when it crashes upon starting:

```
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Unknown repository type at file:/C:/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/128/data/listener_1925729951/.
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you really wanna solve problem, paste error logs and we might be able to help you (paste them to google first). Deleting workspace *solves* nothing, you can use command line parameter to create new workspace.

Comment: @AoeAoe just updated my original question to show the error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends where your previous instance of eclipse stores it.
Default location for them is

```
C:\Users\<username>\workspace\
```

but it can be anywhere as I said.

Check this out : [How to change the eclipse default working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179328/how-to-change-the-eclipse-default-working-directory)

Comment: hmmm, I actually don't have a path like that with. I have  users\username\ but no workspace directory.

Answer (score 8):

Go to Eclipse's window option then go to preferences then type Workspace in top left corner, Under Startup & ShutDown click on Workspace option then you find correct path of Eclipse Workspace.

Answer (score 6):

Go to C:\Users\\eclipse\jee-\eclipse\configuration.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs

RECENT_WORKSPACES has all the workspaces used by that eclipse version.
This solution help when you can't access eclipse (for some weird eclipse reason) to see the workspaces used.

Comment: THIS is the correct answer! All other answers is a "chicken or egg" problem. For example, how can you say that I have to access the menu when eclipse is not running yet. It cannot run bcoz the workspace does not exist. And that setting can be modified in the file described in this answer.

Answer (score 4):

When you create a workspace in Eclipse, it creates a ".metadata" folder in the given location. You should be able to track down your workspaces by searching for those folders on your filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

you can check eclipse folder

eclipse->configuration->.settings->org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs

Answer (score 1):

You will find the file at

{eclipse installed location}\configuration.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs