# Locate every local Eclipse workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I would like to clean up the Ubuntu machine I am working on. In particular, I would like to check for every Eclipse workspace of Java projects eventually abandoned on the machine. Since the machine has been previously used by other users, I do not know how many they are, and how extensively they could be scattere around. Is there a strategy that allows me to do that? By now, I approached the problem as suggested by the answers provided to the question: [How to find my old Eclipse workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329705/how-to-find-my-old-eclipse-workspace])

Unfortunately, I did not find them satisfactory, since they do not allow to proceed with an exhaustive across the whole system.

Comment: How many workspace(s) do you have? And why are they scattered everywhere on the system? Anyway, `locate .metadata` should do it.

Comment: Unknown. The machine has been previously used by other users.

Comment: Have you considered a clean install of Ubuntu?

Comment: Sure, but the system is ok, and there is a lot of stuff that has to be preserved. I am on a more selective approach, then.

Comment: Stuff that has to be preserved should be in source control; not on your machine.

Comment: Perhaps who preceded me what not aware of some good practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Eclipse workspace contains a directory named `.metadata`. Searching for this directory name should give you all workspaces.

```
find / -type d -name '.metadata'
```

If you want to clean up Eclipse installations from the system, check my answer on [How to uninstall Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50855742/897024) for a list of other directories that are usually left behind after removing Eclipse.

Comment: Simple and effective indeed. I did not consider to approach the problem this way. Thank you!