# android, eclipse opens with non current project

Tags: android, eclipse, project

I am working on eclipse to develop my android apps,

I have been working on some project, I have tabs opened and have been running project X.

But if I close eclipse, and open it again later,

Eclipse opens with the tabs i had opened before, but on the "package explorer", a different project is opened

not the one I was working on when I closed Eclipse,

is not a big thing,
just annoying to open all again,

is there a way to have my project opened when I star eclipse, and not some old project?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like default directory setting issue, you can set the workspace directory to the one your projects are in: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519549/824345) link.