# Changing the default location used by Eclipse Neon when creating a new project?

Tags: java, eclipse

Recently I began to store the source code of my projects in a separate directory outside the default workspace to avoid conflicts with my co workers when using the same github repo, which is the reason for this question.

When creating a new Java project in version 4.6 Neon of Eclipse IDE, it shows you the location where the project folder will be created on your disk.

[screenshot - dialogue that opens when creating a new project in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2ehV.png)

It gives you the option to

> "Use default location"

which in my case is the path to my workspace directory.

My question now is, how do I change that default location?
Because I'd like to store all my code outside the workspace, I now need to enter my project folders path when creating a project.

I haven't found anything in the build in preferences nor in any of the forums dealing with Eclipse's features in general.

To clarify my question, I am **not** interested in *changing the workplace location* but rather in setting a default directory where all new projects should be automatically created.

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the eclipse default working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179328/how-to-change-the-eclipse-default-working-directory)

Comment: *to avoid conflicts with my co workers when using the same github repo* - What? Are you working on the same machine or something?

Answer (score 0):

'default location' in the New Project wizard **always** means 'in the workspace', this can't be changed.