# Eclipse on MAC, set current directory to be in Documents folder not APP BUNDLE

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

When I run this code on my MAC OS X in an eclipse web project

```
File file1 = new File("myfile.txt");
if( !file1.exists() ) file1.createNewFile();
System.out.println( file1.getAbsolutePath() );
```

it says

```
/Users/Richard/Desktop/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/myfile.txt
```

on my WINDOWS 7 computer it says

```
C:\Users\Richard\Documents\workspace\myproject\src\com\example\myclass\myfile.txt
```

How do I get my eclipse running on my MAC OS X to output files in my Documents folder like on my WINDOWS 7, instead of going into the Eclipse.app APP BUNDLE and being put into the folder Contents/MacOS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the working directory for any given launch configuration under `Run` -> `Run Configurations...` then under the `Arguments` tab.

It's strange that your default seems to be within the Eclipse.app bundle—normally, it's `${workspace_loc:`*`project name`*`}`.

Unfortunately, it seems you still [can't set the default working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981213/default-eclipse-working-directory) for all new run configurations.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Mac, then:

1. Open the 'Servers' tab.
2. Double click your server.
3. Click 'Open launch configuration'.
4. Click the 'Arguments' tab.
5. In the 'Working directory' pane, choose 'Other' and enter the path you want to have as your working directory.