# Relative path on Eclipse EE

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, path

I'm doing a project in Eclipse EE and tried to give the relative path
to take a file to use as a template to generate a JasperReport report,
but not giving me errors. But if I give an absolute like "D: \ \ template" does not fail.

My question is how do I tell you to choose the relative path to a folder called
"Template-report" that is in: >> src >> project name-reports >> template.jasper templates.

regards

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths in application launched from Eclipse are resolved relative to the application's working directory.  By default, this is the (file system) directory that corresponds to the project, but you can alter it using the application launcher configuration.

This Q&A offers an alternative approach (I think): [Default eclipse working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981213/default-eclipse-working-directory)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use eclipse variables to refer to projects into workspace
look at [this](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcpathvars.htm)