# keystore.jks (for SSL) cannot be found when running project with Intellij IDEA, but is found by Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, intellij-idea

I am using an application context file to setup SSL so as to connect to a queue using Spring JMS. I do this leveraging the MethodInvokingFactoryBean:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
            <property name="targetClass" value="java.lang.System" />
            <property name="targetMethod" value="getProperties" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="putAll" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <util:properties>
            <prop key="javax.net.ssl.trustStore">src\main\resources\META-INF\spring\ssl\truststore.jks
            </prop>
            <prop key="javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword">******</prop>
            <prop key="javax.net.ssl.keyStore">src\main\resources\META-INF\spring\ssl\keystore.jks
            </prop>
            <prop key="javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword">******</prop>
            <prop key="javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType">jks</prop>
        </util:properties>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This works within eclipse without any issue. However when run with IDEA it doesn't seem to find the keyStore file and hence can't connect causing an SSL Handshake failure.

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\META-INF\spring\ssl\keystore.jks (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

The project is a standard maven project. Both Eclipse and IDEA are using the same JRE and have the resources folder included in the build path. Any help as to why this is happening is appreciated. Also if any other info is required let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IntelliJ the working directory is different then Eclipse. Check the launch config in IDEA and set it accordingly. If I remember correctly in Eclipse its the workspace and in IDEA the whole project. See [Run/Debug Configuration: Application](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-application.html) (Remember, in IDEA the project is the workspace)  and [Default eclipse working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981213/default-eclipse-working-directory)

Comment: That's great. The working directory was set to where I keep my workspaces (separate location). Pointing it to the code has fixed everything. Feel a little silly now, Thank you!